# routing does not work, getting nil when trying to access a method in rails 4 controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a method in my controller that should return every user in the db.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 # before_action :set_user, only: [:show]
  def index
       @users = User.all
  end
```

if I check for User.all in my terminal (rails c) I am getting a bunch of results, but if I am calling it from my view

```
 <div>
    <% @users.each do |user| %>
      <%= user %>
    <% end %>
 </div>
```

I am getting `undefined method`each' for nil:NilClass`

I included the users resource in my routes

```
PROJECT::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :users
```

any ideas what am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is not with routes. You dont have users at all. So it says undefined method each for nil class

```
@users.each
```

@users is empty. You have not done anything yet that would use your routes to go to controller to do some action.

Use User.all.to_a in controller

Comment: What should I do to make it go to the controller and get all the users?

Comment: Do you have users in your database ?
Found this for rails 4 . No longer will a call to Model.all execute a query immediately and return an array of records. In Rails 4, calls to Model.all is equivalent to now deprecated Model.scoped. This means that more relations can be chained to Model.all and the result will be lazily evaluated.

Comment: use Model.all.to_a  . Edited the answer

Comment: I tried to find an online example for this , but I could not. Will you be able to give me an example on how to use it?

Comment: What do you want to do in the first place ? Just list all the users ? in that case use User.all.to_a in controller instead of User.all. This will give you an array of user objects instead of an active record relation. Then @users.each loops through your array. iv you just display <%= user %> it will display the whole object. Instead access the attributes you want to . For ex if you wan to display names do <%= user.name %> considering name is an attribute of user model. You have not yet reached a position where you would be using routes and all.

Comment: I want to create a list of user.name that I will use for an autocomplete input field

Comment: I suppose the op could also put `unless @users.nil?` after the `end` of the loop in the view.

Comment: If to_a is used and there are no users you will get an EMPTY array, and rails (don't know about 4)doesn't give error on [].each. So is that unless really needed ??

Comment: @Quantico then you can probably collect only the names from the DB
User.all.pluck(&:name). This will return you the names of all users in DB.

Comment: No, if you `to_a` then you're golden, don't need anything else. I meant my suggestion as an alternative, not an addition. I was saying you could use the `to_a`, or here's another method that would work equally well. Depending on the coding style, I'd even argue that `unless` is cleaner from a readability standpoint (if one wanted to get really picky and semantic). In the end, either option is fine.

Comment: @Teeg I get you. Thank you. I kinda always prefer minimizing conditions in view. That was my approach.

Comment: @0v3rc10ck3d Yeah fair enough. I tend to do the opposite. Either's good.